# Must a "is defined" macro check and its call be in separate conditions?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I was struggling to find an answer amoung many that refer to this topic on SO, but here's some seemingly innocent looking code that fails to compile when `F` is not a defined macro,

```
int main() {
#if defined(F) && F(0, 2, 0)
  return 0;
#endif
  return 1;
}
```

The problem, according to [this section of the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html) is that inside `#if` expressions "all macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression’s value begins", so this in an invalid check, since when `F` is undefined, I see,

```
test.cpp:2:20: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if defined(F) && F(0, 2, 0)
                    ^
```

My question: is the only way to correctly do this check like so?

```
int main() {
#if defined(F)
#if F(0, 2, 0)
  return 0;
#endif
#endif
  return 1;
}
```

I find this quite ugly and unintuitive, so I'm hoping there's a nicer way to do such things in the preprocessor.

Comment: It may be ugly and intuitive to you, but breaking it into nested `#if`/`#endif` is the only option you have.     In C++ (definitely) and in C (more often than not) using function-like macros is discouraged anyway so it may pay to find a solution to your problem that avoids or minimises use of macros.    As described, it's not obvious WHY you need to do this in particular, so nobody can help you with that.

Comment: With MSVC10 the first one works for me too

Comment: With slight change to constraints I would define a default `#define F(a,b,c) 0`

Comment: So in what case would `F` not be defined? What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: a function with two returns? Maybe use a #else before   return 1;.

Comment: @Peter: Macros are to be used with caution and sparesely, but nevertheless they are a relevant part of the language. In C more (constants) than C++, but in some places they are reasonable in C++, too sometimes. This one looks like a valid use-case (until proof of the opposite). There is a difference between programming practice and theory.

Comment: @Olaf - I said macros are discouraged, not that they are forbidden, and suggested the OP consider an alternative approach.  There are plenty of ways to avoid macros, depending on what the real task is, for which the OP has decided to use macros.

Comment: I apologise for not giving more context, `F` in real life is a version check macro exported from a 3rd party library. In my case I had the wrong version of the 3rd party library where it did not export said macro. The macro in this case is a reasonable use, now I've learned it's just the usage of the macro that is wrong in the client of the library. Thanks for all the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `F` macro is defined in some header file, you could place the following code somewhere between the include and its first usage:

```
#ifndef F
#define F(a,b,c) 0
#endif
```

Or another reasonable default. That's a common solution for your problem. Another is to not allow such macros to be
not defined, but require either the default value or whatever it's expected to do. This latter approach is
a bit safer for e.g. configuration files, as it makes clear the author did consider the macro and intentionally
picked a value (i.e. he did not just forget to define it). It's also easier if the definition is in the same file.

Your test would then just be:

```
#if F(0, 2, 0)
```

Avoiding the nested condition (which would cause additional trouble if there was an `#else` required somewhere.

Two words of advise:

- Use macros carefully and sparesely, only when reasonble. Expecially C++ provides features which reduce the need for macros.
- Don't use single-letter names for macros. Remember they are textual replacements, bejond the normal language syntax. Use self-explanatory names instead (this does not only apply to macros, but for those it's even more relevant).

Comment: Thanks, in the real example F is 3RD_PARTY_LIBBRARY_CHECK_VERSION, this was a new macro introduced as part of a library update I didn't have. My take away here is to use the nested conditions (ugly version) to future proof against other users trying to compile against an older version of the lib. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Identifiers may not start with a digit. Nevertheless, I hoped you did (and I'm fine using a short name in an example), but questions and answers are to be helpful for future readers, so I had to add the warning(s). In contrast to some other users I use the most appropriate construct and if that means macros, I'm fine with them.

Comment: Agreed, yet again I made up a name, it's a dumb library name that wouldn't mean anything on SO, hopefully it will still be useful for future readers if they hit this one :)

Comment: Check my recent answers. I wouldn't have answered if I didn't think it's worth it. As I wrote: no need to use the actual name (but - seriously: you cannot have a macro name starting with a digit. Thatä#s simply not allowed by the language; it would be interpreted as a number with invalid characters following. Hmm …